# What can I do if my fish catch viral hemorrhagic septicemia (aka Fish Ebola)?

Tags: fish, diseases

I have a friend who just got some new fish from somewhere that she had gotten fish from many times before without any issues.

However, after introducing them to her tank, it turns out they had VHS, and it started to infect her other fish.

This was something I'd never heard of before. I am planning to get fish of my own in the near future, and was wondering what to do if my fish ever caught VHS. Is it possible to cure them, or prevent it from spreading?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is put them down.they might keep on spreading this deadly disease,

Comment: My uninformed instinctive response would be to sterilize everything at least to the bleach-and/or-boiling level, and replace anything which can't survive that treatment (obviously including the fish). Autoclave (superheated steam) would be better but isn't generally available at home. If you use bleach, of course, be sure to follow with a bleach detoxifier and/or many cycles of clear water to avoid poisoning le poisson.